# Universal covering space of X x classifying space of \pi_1(X)

Tags: differential-geometry, algebraic-topology, lie-groups

I am trying to learn about classifying spaces for a Lie group $G$.
The question I have is the following:

> Suppose $X$ is a manifold and $G=\pi_1(X)$ is its fundamental group, is it true that $p:\tilde{X}\rightarrow X$ is a universal principal $G$-bundle?

I think it is not true in general, because I read somewhere in the book " Fiber Bundles" by Husemoller that a classifying principal bundle (P,B,G) must have the property that P is contractible.

Can anyone please make things clearer for me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is false in general as Lee Mosher illustrated, but nevertheless true for an interesting class of examples, namely [aspherical](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aspherical_space) manifolds. Covering maps induce isomorphisms on all higher homotopy groups, so if the manifold $M$ is aspherical, it's universal covering space $\tilde{M}$ is aspherical too and furthermore simply connected, hence all homotopy groups vanish and since all manifolds have the homotopy type of CW complexes, the universal $\tilde{M}$ is contractible by the [Whitehead theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whitehead_theorem). That implies that the universal covering is a universal $\pi_1(M)$-bundle.

A large class of aspherical example come from the [theorem of Cartan-Hadamard](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartan%E2%80%93Hadamard_theorem), which proves the asphericality of all manifolds admitting a complete non-positively curved Riemmannian metric.

In this context, it is also worth mentioning [the Borel conjecture](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Borel_conjecture) which basically says, that closed aspherical manifolds are topologically completely determined by their fundamental group.

Answer (score 3):

A counter-example always has a clarifying effect: $\mathbb{R} P^2$ is a manifold, $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$ is its fundamental group, and $p : S^2 \to \mathbb{R} P^2$ is its universal cover. And $S^2$, of course, is not contractible.